# Add keyboard glyphs to markdown (working with both html + latex)

Tags: fonts, markdown, r-markdown

I'd like to add keyboard glyphs to a document I'm creating with R markdown/bookdown to make it easy to show the reader some specific key combinations e.g., alt-tab, cmd-arrow up etc.

For latex something like the menukeys package can be used to generate the keys, but I'd like a combination where the same input markdown code can be converted to both html and pdf.

For example the following R markdown code (adapted from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/keyboard-font-for-latex)) produces the correct output for pdf. Is it possible to somehow add code to change the `\keys{}` so that it will also render for html?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "John Doe"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{menukeys}
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
# htmltools::tagList(rmarkdown::html_dependency_font_awesome())
```

## This section shows possible key combinations

You can also visualize \keys{\tab}, \keys{\capslock}, \keys{\Space}, 
\keys{\arrowkeyup} and many more.
````

Right now my best *ad hoc* solution is to run the markdown file through perl/awk/sed and replace the `\keys{}` code with something else that might work for html, but I'd prefer to get things running directly and possibly only change css and pandoc options